# How to add global interfaces to Nuxt project

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I just started with Nuxt 3 and have been having some trouble with using typescript functionality.

I am trying to build a general NavBar that can have multiple buttons with different links. For this I wanted to make an interface that I can pass as an array to the component.

Something like:

```
interface Button {
  icon: string,
  link: string
}
```

Is there some way to make interfaces that are visible throughout my whole project? I can't find a lot about typescript integration for Nuxt.

Comment: What I do is just a root folder `/types` with an `index.ts` that exports every type one by one. This way you can easily include them with `import { type, anotherType, an wholeOtherType } from '~/types'` without too much work.

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to `Tea_lover_418`, I tried what he suggested in the comment and it works even better with `global` declaration.

At the root of your project create a directory named `types` with an `index.ts` file, add your global types declaration like in the example below. That's it, you don't need to import anything it's available globally.

```
// ~/types/index.ts

export { };

declare global {
  type SomeType = [boolean, string, number]; 

  interface MyFancyInterface {
    ...
  }

  const enum GlobalConstEnum {
    ...
  }

  ....
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Few corrections to [Fennec answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73237686/502261).

1. I would add index.**d**.ts instead of index.ts and ideal case it should be generated.

```ts
// ~/types/index.d.ts

export { MyInterface };

declare global {
  interface MyInterface {
        some_field: number
    }
}
```

2. To you tsconfig.json you should add includes (plural)

```json
  {
    "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
    "includes": [
      "types/*.d.ts"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**One correction to Gleb's answer** - "include" should be "includes" (plural)

```
{
    "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json", 
    "includes": [ "types/*.d.ts", ] 
}
```

Singular caused useNuxtApp and other Nuxt features to become 'unknown'. Plural worked perfectly.

Comment: includes (as in plural) is not working for me. Yes, the Nuxt imports (ref, computed, useNuxtApp etc. do not get overwritten, but MyInterface does not get imported